# why is the order writen in css making a difference to my design

Tags: css

In my CSS  I have the following:

```
.myDiv{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}

.yellow{
    background:#faf8c7;
}

.lightGrey{
    background:#f8f8f8;
}
```

In my HTML

```
<div class="myDiv lightGrey yellow"></div>
```

This should display the `div` as the yellow colour but instead it is lightGrey.
If I change the order of the .yellow and .lightGrey in my CSS (not HTML) then the `div` becomes yellow...why is this?

Surely it should be the order that the classes are written in the HTML that determines whether the `div` is yellow or grey. The order of the CSS should be irrelevant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> surely it should be the order that the classes are written in the html that determines whether the div is yellow or grey

It's [how the cascade was defined](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade):

> 1. Find all declarations that apply to the element and property in question, for the target [media type](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html). Declarations apply if the associated selector [matches](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) the element in question and the target medium matches the media list on all @media rules containing the declaration and on all links on the path through which the style sheet was reached.
> 2. Sort according to importance (normal or important) and origin (author, user, or user agent). In ascending order of precedence:
>
>    1. user agent declarations
>    2. user normal declarations
>    3. author normal declarations
>    4. author important declarations
>    5. user important declarations
> 3. Sort rules with the same importance and origin by [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) of selector: more specific selectors will override more general ones. Pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes are counted as normal elements and classes, respectively.
> 4. Finally, sort by order specified: if two declarations have the same weight, origin and specificity, the latter specified wins. Declarations in imported style sheets are considered to be before any declarations in the style sheet itself.

#4 is the part you're struggling with, the declarations have identical [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity), and therefore the latter one is winning.

Comment: Thanks zzzzBov, and I know you are right, however I always thought that the last class that was written in the markup would overwrite what had come before if they had the same specificity.. but this is not the case!

Answer (score 1):

[**Cascading**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade) Style Sheet.

That means that style that appears later in the stylesheet will overwrite style that appeared earlier in the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

since all rules have the same specificity, the last one (for the meaning of *Cascade*) specified in the `CSS` wins. In other words, no matter you re-arrange your classes in the markup, with the given style your background is always lightgray.

> Surely it should be the order that the classes are written in the HTML that determines whether the div is yellow or grey. The order of the CSS should be irrelevant.

for the above explanation it's the opposite

Comment: downvoter could care to explain his vote? (if there're valid reason, of course)

Answer (score 0):

order in your html code of each class `myDiv lightGrey yellow` is not important at all, it's like you say : I bought 3 colors, but we don't know what is the first or the last you bought